# Javascript -filtering object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to do something in pure JS.  I have an Object like so

```
var data = {
    "Something": true,
    "Something else": false,
    "Blah": false,
    "a fish ISA": true
};
```

What I want to do is filter anything which has true to its own Object.  At the moment I am trying

```
var thingFunctions = Object.keys(data).filter(function(e) {
    return typeof data[e] == 'function'
});
```

But I think this is incorrect.  How can I get the data with a value of true to its own Object?

Thanks

Comment: `typeof data[e] == 'function'` has nothing to with true or false booleans - you should be looking at something like `typeof data[e] == 'boolean' && !!(data[e])`

Comment: or just `data[e] === true`

Comment: @pandorym Indeed, just wanted to stay in the style provided :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a new object instead of just an array of the keys that point to a value of `true` (not truthy such as `1` or `"hello"`):

```
var onlyTrues = {};

for (var prop in data) {
  if (data[prop] === true) {
    onlyTrues[prop] = data[prop];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So firstly you have no functions inside `data`, so doing a check on functions will return nothing.

```
var data = {
    "Something": true,
    "Something else": false,
    "Blah": false,
    "a fish ISA": true
};

var thingFunctions = Object.keys( data ).filter(function( e ) {
    return data[ e ] === true;
});

console.log( thingFunctions );

// Will result in [ 'Something', 'a fish ISA' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were asking for an object.

I use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the iteration over the keys and an empty object for the result `filtered`, because I can not filter objects:

```js
var data = {
        "Something": true,
        "Something else": false,
        "Blah": false,
        "a fish ISA": true
    },
    filtered = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
    if (data[e] === true) {                      // explicit testing for boolean and true!
        filtered[e] = data[e];
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

As you want to only have all true value we can convert them to true false values by doing the following.

```
!!({}) // true
!!([]) // true
!!('') // false
!!(true) // true
!!(false) // false
...
```

With this we can see if any data type is true or false by doing the following.

```
var thingFunctions = Object.keys(data).filter(function(e) {
    return !!(data[e]);
});
```

Comment: This would return `false` when the value is `true`, is that correct?

Comment: But the OP wants an object where only the `true` objects remain, this would do the opposite. You would need a double operator: `!!data[e]`.

Comment: In that case you case do it again !!() this will convert it to a true false value and not convert it.

Comment: No it will not. `!!(false) === false` and `!!(true) === true` - What you are doing is `!(false) === true` because you invert their boolean only once. Which means you are returning `false` for elements that have a value of `true`, which means they wont be included in the eventual output of the `filter`.

Comment: Is that better? I first thought he wanted the opposite values I apologize.

Comment: No problem, you might have noticed I liked the change ;)